# How to Specify the Version number for a SQL Server DB Project(on Dacpac)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

How to Specify the Version number for a SQL Server DB Project. This is associateed to Dacpac

Like [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Data-Tier Application version in the "Properties" of the `.dacpac` inside the database project settings.

[image: SSDT Project settings dialog showing Data-Tier Application Properties modal]

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. But this version number is not getting associated to dacpac as it happens for a Assembly. is there anything else to get that. Also is it possible to refer this  version number in code as we do in an assembly.

Comment: @Pavank Are you deploying to SQL Server or Azure SQL? If not Azure SQL, did you try the following query to check if the version is being updated in the database? SELECT * FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysdac_instances]